# Swift Bridging Header - Use of undeclared type 'MMLANScannerDelegate'

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode9, bridging-header

I successfully installed this Objective C library [MMLanScan](https://github.com/mavris/MMLanScan), successfully created a bridging header file, and successfully built my project without compile time errors.

But now when I extend from `MMLANScannerDelegate` I get a compile-time error, for example compiling this

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, MMLANScannerDelegate {

    // ...

}
```

results in this error

> Use of undeclared type 'MMLANScannerDelegate'

Here is my bridging header file which I successfully compiled, so I'm not sure what the problem is

```
#ifndef BridingHeader_h
#define BridingHeader_h

#import "MMLanScan/MMLANScanner.h"
#import "MMLanScan/LANProperties.h"
#import "MMLanScan/PingOperation.h"
#import "MMLanScan/MMLANScanner.h"
#import "MMLanScan/MACOperation.h"
#import "MMLanScan/MacFinder.h"
#import "MMLanScan/MMDevice.h"

#endif
```

Comment: You shouldn't need an `#ifdef` guard on your bridging header.  Could that be blocking it?  Does it work without that, by chance?

Comment: @Ssswift I get the same error if I delete the guard

Comment: @the_prole get any further with this?